# Is this the correct way to run a script at certain hours?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, cron

I'd like a cron job to run a command at:

- 8am
- 10am
- 5pm
- 7pm
- 9pm
- 11pm

I've tried this, but when I check my logs, I see that the command is run too many times.

```
* 8,10,17,19,21,23 * * * COMMAND >> mylog.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command means "run on every minute of the given hours". If you want to run it just once, you need to set the minute field, e.g.:

```
0 8,10,17,19,21,23 * * * COMMAND >> mylog.txt
```

This way the command only runs at the start (minute 0) of each of the given hours